# CSS transition not working when use overflow?

Tags: html, css, transition

I have this code below

```css
body {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: black;
}

.fillColor {
  color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 40px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
  ;
}

.fillColor:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
}

.fillColor:after {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 10s;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.fillColor:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p class="fillColor" data-hover="HUNG"></p>
```

But when I remove `overflow: hidden` in css. **My code isn't run.** 
I have no idea with this. I tried remove and have error.

Anyone can explain me with this.

I know `overflow:hidden` prevent text not float out of parent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you could tell us more about what went wrong, that'd make it *much* easier for us to help you. Also, while we're at it, if you haven't already, check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's considered on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what an overflow:hidden is doing is just hiding the scrollbars.

Try editing the overflow with scroll and you'll see

```
overflow:scroll
```

However if you remove overflow:hidden, the element fillColor:after will be rendered as visible.

Comment: Nope. When i use overflow:hidden. Transitions will run smoothly.

Comment: Yes, It'll not run when overflow:hidden is not used. That's why I recommend you to try overflow:scroll, it's almost the same as overflow:hidden. The only difference is when it is set in scroll, you'll see both of vertical and horizontal scroll bars in which overflow:hidden hides.

Answer (score 0):

In css the *overflow* property specifies whether content of a block container element is clipped when it overflows the element's box.

Value *hidden* means the content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided.

So, if your element **.fillColor:after** has **width:0** and **overflow:hidden** properties, its content clipped to 0px width and not visible, but if you remove **overflow:hidden**, content no clipps anymore and text floats out of the **.fillColor:after** element and has its own width.